# Using spinner inside a Dialog in an Non actvity class

Tags: android-studio, constructor, spinner, android-dialogfragment

I'm trying to implement a spinner inside a Dialog, it is named UserClassDialog.java(non activity class), as shown below:

```
public class UserClassDialog extends AppCompatDialogFragment {
 @NonNull
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState)  {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

        LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_dialog, null);

        Spinner spinner = view.findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.courses);
}
```

But, of course it would be an error because using "this" would be an error inside a non activity class.  My question is, how can use this spinner in an Non activity class? Is it by using a constructor? If yes, how?

Also this is my code for the mainactivity(named UserClass.class) which calls the dialog box, as shown below:

```
public class UserClasses extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_user_classes);
}
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater =getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.class_menu, menu); //Layout for the dialog 
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()){
            case R.id.add: // the add icon on the class_menu layout to open the dialog
                openDialog();
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }

    }

    public void openDialog() {
            UserClassDialog userClassDialog = new UserClassDialog();
            userClassDialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "user class dialog");

    }
```

Comment: try getContext() or getApplicationContext() in place of this. Maybe It will work fine.

Comment: yup thanks problem solved but can I use bundle to pass onitemselected string value to the oncreatedialog?